# Microsoft Phone HTC and development

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have heard a lot about MS Phone HTC and wondering if any developer has used them. If so, what is the first step toward development this device with no experience in phone programming?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell, where to begin. First of all start by visiting this page and **download+install the WP8 SDK:**
https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/develop
Note you need **Windows 8 x64 Pro** and newer CPU to run the SDK and the emulator (Core-i5 or better is recommended).

Then I would recommend reading some **book about C# development** and/or start testing various **samples provided with the SDK** here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx
and also here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/

This is a nice free ebook about C# from Charles Petzold:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to sign up for Microsoft's [Generation App](http://aka.ms/8in30) program - it's a free, staged set of training and resources leading you through the process of designing, developing, monetizing, and submitting your app. It's essentially a curated set of links, documents, samples, etc. delivered in a daily e-mail.

I know you mentioned HTC, but Nokia also has a great developer program they are rolling out at http://dvlup.com; it's in limited preview at the moment, but you can submit your e-mail and be notified when it's fully open.

Comment: Can I start off with Visual Studio and an emulator for time being? do I really would need a real cell phone and connection for that to start ?

Comment: Yes, for most of scenarios you don't need a real device, but it's required for some advanced areas like testing NFC, Bluetooth or Camera input.

Answer (score 1):

As for the device, I own HTC's 8x and I'm developing apps on it with success. The device choice is up to you, whatever you like better.

As for resources to begin programming. It depends whether you have .NET programming background at all. If you do, all you really need is on [Windows Phone Dev Center](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us). With a bit of patience and passion you will succeed :)

It's also worth buying a good book as it guides you through the whole process.